# pragma directive in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios4, pragma

When i create a UITableViewController class, the template has some #pragma directives:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle
```

at the start and:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source
```

at the beginning of the implementation of the data source methods.
I know that `#pragma` is a compiler directive, but why do we need to notify the compiler of the above?
Does this mean that we have to give a `#pragma` directive every time we implement any kind of data source/delegate protocols?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You dont need to use them. They are simply for code "prettiness" and separating methods.

In my screenshot example, they are used to draw the lines you see, separating delegates.

`#pragma mark -` draws the line and `#pragma mark My Delegates` shows you whatever text you see in **BOLD**.

[image]

Comment: Pragma marks are an essential code documenting tool and the most addictive of all. I love them.

Comment: Note that these pragma marks don't work if xcode has the preference set to sort the methods. If you see all your methods and then the pragma comments at the bottom, go into xcode preferences and turning sorting off. I'd love apple to fix it so that sorting is done within pragmas. Then it would be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to WrightsCS's absolutely correct answer, I want to point out something else:

If you want to use pragma's on your own, just drop the first line and move the dash to the second line.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View Lifecycle
```

and

`#pragma mark - View Lifecycle`

produce exactly the same.